# Absolute latout margin has diffrent effect on android 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout

i design an xml layout for my android app and i use layout margin top and left for putting somethings on a special place every thing is ok on android 2.3 and higher and all element are on own place but on adroid 2.2 (fedora) element aren't on own place (some times higher and sometimes lower)
whats the problem
this is my xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/carbg"
    android:layout_width="2000dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-400dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">


<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/SplashImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cars" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false" android:scaleType="center"/>

<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="397dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
    android:src="@drawable/driver1" android:visibility="visible" android:scaleType="center"/>

<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/driver2" android:layout_marginLeft="355dp" android:layout_marginTop="290dp" android:visibility="invisible" android:scaleType="center"/>


<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/splashsigns"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/splashsign"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="245dp" android:scaleType="center"/>


<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="630dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="264dp"
    android:src="@drawable/danger"
    android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:scaleType="center"/>



 <ImageView
     android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
     android:id="@+id/imageView2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/wheel" android:layout_marginTop="363dp" android:layout_marginLeft="535dp" android:scaleType="center"/>

 <ImageView
     android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/wheel" android:layout_marginTop="361dp" android:layout_marginLeft="206dp" android:scaleType="center"/>
```

my problem is with all image views
i know that the problem is using absolute margin layout but how
fix this problem i want have a same page for all android vesion
this 2pic descript my problem better
[image]

the problem is android icone

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
<ImageView
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/SplashImageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
android:src="@drawable/cars" 
android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="false" android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try out different option of `android:scaleType` it would help you out from this problem i have solved using `android:scaleType="matrix"` you try out different